# Erro ao usar .length na resposta do AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, array

Tenho o seguinte ajax.

```
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    ajax.open("GET", 'http://localhost/erp/api/v1/itens.php');

    ajax.responseType = "json";

    ajax.send();
    ajax.addEventListener("readystatechange" , function () {
      
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){

          var response = ajax.response;

          console.log(response.length);  
          
        }
    })
```

Porem o Console.log(reponse.length) me traz 'undefined', sendo q se eu imprimir o reponse me traz 6 dados, o PHP que traz os dados é este.

```
      $i = 1;
      while($lista = $this->ListarDados()):
          $produtos[$i] = array(
                'idProduto'=> $lista['id_Produto'],
                'nomeProduto' => $lista['nomeProduto'],
                'referencia' => $lista['referencia'],
                'custo' => str_replace(".", ",", $lista['custo']),
                'venda' => str_replace(".", ",", $lista['venda']),
                'lucro' => str_replace(".", ",", $lista['lucro'])
           );
           $i++;
       endwhile;
       echo json_encode($produtos);
```

Essa é a resposta do php

```
 {"1":{"idProduto":"20","nomeProduto":"teste","referencia":"as2","custo":"10,00","venda":"30,00","lucro":"20,00"},"2":{"idProduto":"21","nomeProduto":"Atacado do Body","referencia":"222","custo":"11,00","venda":"26,55","lucro":"15,55"}}
```

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: É necessário mostrar o que é retornado do seu código PHP. Como não podemos como o JSON está sendo formado ou retornado, fica difícil dar uma resposta. Favor [edit] sua pergunta, adicionando um [mcve]

Comment: Editado @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Respondi a pergunta. O problema está nos índices do seu array.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é gerado porque seu array não possui índices "regulares" para que seja retornado como um array no JSON. **Você começou a contagem do array através do 1 e não do 0**.

Se você tiver esse array abaixo, isso vai falhar:

```php
$arr = [1 => 'zero', 2 => 'dois'];
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Isso vai gerar

```js
{"1":"zero","2":"dois"}
```

Esse retorno equivale a um `Object` em Javascript e o mesmo não possuo o valor `length`.

O ideal no seu caso seria utilizar `array_values` para "resetar os índices", já que quer retornar um array em JSON.

```php
echo json_encode(array_values($arr));
```

Isso retornará:

```js
["zero","dois"]
```

### Dica 2

Você pode trocar o seu `$i` para `0`. Isso vai gerar um "array regular" no PHP.

### Dica 3

Você pode trocar

`$produtos[$i] = array()`

Por:

`$produtos[] = array()`

Isso irá adicionar os itens do `array` de forma que comece do `0`

Assim, você conseguirá acessar o `length`.

### Dica 4

Caso não queira retorna a saída do PHP, basta tratá-la pelo Javascript. Use `Object.values` para transformar os valores do `Object` em `Array`.

```js
console.log(Object.values(response).length);
```

Comment: Perfeito, nao sabia desta parte de array_values(). 
Muito obrigado  @WallaceMaxters